# "Married since" in Bavarian

Tags: english-to-german, bavarian

My Bayrisch friend is getting married and I want to get him and his wife an FC Bayern jersey set that when they are next to each other will say “Married Since 2018.”

I think the translation is: “verheiratet seit 2018.” So, one jersey would be the number 20 with “verheiratet” below and the other would be “seit” with the number 18 (picture above).

[image: "20, verheiratet"]
[image: "18, seit"]

Is this proper German? More important, is it proper Bavarian? I’d like it to sound like something a Münchner would say rather than something Google Translate would say!

Comment: If she walks or stands right of him they might get some "You don't look your age comments."

Comment: As a general remark: "Verheiratet seit" does not lend itself very well to be written in *bayrisch*, because it does not have any words that distinctly show the dialect. It will mostly look like it was misspelled.

Comment: You should definitely make sure your friends are FC Bayern fans, otherwise this will turn out quite a shame!

Comment: @Sebastian  ... and that your friends are interested in football at all. Imagine, there are people who are completely not interested in that subject and would never wear a T-shirt slightly close to football gear.

Comment: Not to spoil the idea but besides the fact that the constellation of year and text is wrong, it is as you said "when they are next to each other". If not then this will make no sense at all and they might get tired of answering startled peoples' question about the meaning. So perhaps you want to change the text to something that makes sense without the counterpart too.

Answer (score 24):

As several other answers already point out, "2018 verheiratet seit" is neither proper German nor Bavarian. However, it seems like with the layout given by the T-Shirt, you need to have the "FC Bayern München" at the top, the 20 and 18 below, and the other two words below the numbers, in the spot where player names go.

This leaves you with "2018 verheiratet seit" or "2018 seit verheiratet", which are both wrong.

So as an alternative, I'd suggest something like "2018 Hochzeit g'hobt" or even "2018 hamma g'heirat" which sounds way more natural to my ears.

I'm from south Germany, and have spent 15 years in Bavaria, but am not a bavarian, so don't rely on my spelling. Maybe someone with a better bavarian background can improve on that.

Comment: I think the meaning is immediately clear when seeing both shirts next to each other in the proper order, even if "verheiratet seit" is written below "20 18".
I really don't get how people perceive that as wrong. "Verheiratet seit 2018" is what my brain automatically patches together when parsing what is written there.

Answer (score 18):

Well,

> verheiratet seit 2018

is proper German, and usual in Bavaria too. But your shirts don't say *»verheiratet seit 2018«*. They say:

> 2018 verheiratet seit

which is not proper German. It is like

> 2018 married since

in English.

Yoda says:

> Word order you must respect.

Comment: Wouldn't that be "respect word order you must".

Comment: Aber im Kontext eines Trikots verständlich es ist.

Comment: @Bent - more like "Respect word order you must. Mmmmmhmhhh."

Comment: Word order respect you must!

Answer (score 6):

I am from the northern part of Bavaria.

As stated from Hubert the correct german version is "Verheiratet seit 2018".

However if you want to go for (southern) bavarian dialect its like "verheiat seit 2018". Because it is a spoken dialect there is no correct spelling so it could also be "verhaiat" or "vahaiat".

But I would go for

> Verheiat seit 2018

since the reading fits better.

Comment: No. The r must stay. »Vahairat seit 2018« would be ok in dialect

Comment: I am pretty sure that the 'r' is not correct there. I have never heard someone say it with an 'r'. You can even google it: Vahaiat (422 results), Vahairat (10 results)

Comment: Without the 'r', it strikes me as a tidbit gschert, to be honest.

Comment: Seeing as almost every village has their own dialect anyways, I'd go with the 'r'. It looks complete wrong without the 'r', even knowing that it's written in dialect, especially if the dialect of the other Baierisch guy is differet (i.e., more southern).

Answer (score 1):

The formulation given in the question is perfectly proper German. 
that makes it automatically *not* proper Bavarian, by definition.

If this is asking for a translation into "[Bavarian](https://bar.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boarisch)" it might need to respect the local dialect and not use the High German variant, although it will be understood there [probably](https://www.tz.de/muenchen/stadt/na-servus-in-muenchen-redet-fast-keiner-mehr-bairisch-9551083.html) as well.

The local dialect would sound more like this: [Boarische Hozad](https://bar.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boarische_Hozad) but possibly using the first word as "bairische".

One variant actually suggested by a translation service then reads

> [vaheiratet seit](https://respekt-empire.de/Translator/?page=translateEngine)

Weaknesses of dubious machine translations aside:  With nearly all dialects this spelling is [not codified](https://bar.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boarische_Dialekte_im_Vagleich) for the whole region of Bavarian dialects. It is not even strictly codified for the Munich variant. There is some leeway in choosing the right letters to include in this short quip. Maybe *"vahairod"*? (Within the context given the *"seit"* seems almost optional.)

In my view this is quite a legitimate choice  and it will be understood and appreciated.
The conventions for printing stuff on a sports dress make this layout given in the question quite understandable. No real need to change that.

One might opt for a more formal phrase as the basis.  That still highlights local language variants and adds a slightly humorous variant.  Further it should also satisfie the sticklers that cannot read the usual prints on sports dresses. It might be read as follows:

**"20 18 –– [Eh](https://bar.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eh) gschlossn".**